# Can not read data from firebase as List in android

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read many articles but still my problem is continuing, while fetching data from firebase as list. could you please help me on this.

> Error:  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert
>   object of type java.lang.String to type SubCategoryLoad Object

[Firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btE5X.png)

[image]

---

--> Loading data from firebase:

```
mSubCategoryDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user_post_add_database_ref").child("yeswanth599").child(mCategoryNameReceive);


    mSubCategoryDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,SubCategoryLoad>> genericTypeIndicator=new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,SubCategoryLoad>>(){};
            (-->Error Showing in this Line)   Map<String,SubCategoryLoad> map=(Map<String, SubCategoryLoad>)postSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);
                assert map != null;
                mSubCategoryLoad=new ArrayList<>(map.values());

            }

            mSubCategoryAdapter = new SubCategoryDisplayAdapter(getContext(), mSubCategoryLoad);

            mSubCategoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSubCategoryAdapter);
            mSubCategoryProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSubCategoryProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

---

--> SubCategoryLoad.Class

public class SubCategoryLoad {

```
private String mUserPostAddress;

private String mUserPostBusinessEndTime;

private String mUserPostBusinessSelectedCity;

private String mUserPostBusinessSelectedCountry;

private String mUserPostBusinessStartTime;

private String mUserPostCategory;

private String mUserPostEmail;

private List<UserPostAdsImages> mUserPostImages;

private String mUserPostName;

private String mUserPostPhonenumber;

private List<UserPostAdsLanguages> mUserPostSupportingLanguage;

private String mUserPostWebsite;


public SubCategoryLoad() {
    //empty constructor needed
}

public SubCategoryLoad(String userPostAddress, String userPostBusinessEndTime,
                       String userPostBusinessSelectedCity, String userPostBusinessSelectedCountry,
                       String userPostBusinessStartTime, String userPostCategory,
                       String userPostEmail, List<UserPostAdsImages> userPostImages,
                       String userPostName, String userPostPhonenumber,
                       List<UserPostAdsLanguages> userPostSupportingLanguage, String userPostWebsite
) {

    mUserPostAddress = userPostAddress;
    mUserPostBusinessEndTime = userPostBusinessEndTime;
    mUserPostBusinessSelectedCity = userPostBusinessSelectedCity;
    mUserPostBusinessSelectedCountry = userPostBusinessSelectedCountry;
    mUserPostBusinessStartTime = userPostBusinessStartTime;
    mUserPostCategory = userPostCategory;
    mUserPostEmail = userPostEmail;
    mUserPostImages = userPostImages;
    mUserPostName = userPostName;
    mUserPostPhonenumber = userPostPhonenumber;
    mUserPostSupportingLanguage = userPostSupportingLanguage;
    mUserPostWebsite = userPostWebsite;


}


public void setUserPostAddress(String userPostAddress) {
    this.mUserPostAddress = userPostAddress;
}

public void setUserPostBusinessEndTime(String userPostBusinessEndTime) {
    this.mUserPostBusinessEndTime = userPostBusinessEndTime;
}

public void setUserPostBusinessSelectedCity(String userPostBusinessSelectedCity) {
    this.mUserPostBusinessSelectedCity = userPostBusinessSelectedCity;
}

public void setUserPostBusinessSelectedCountry(String userPostBusinessSelectedCountry) {
    this.mUserPostBusinessSelectedCountry = userPostBusinessSelectedCountry;
}

public void setUserPostBusinessStartTime(String userPostBusinessStartTime) {
    this.mUserPostBusinessStartTime = userPostBusinessStartTime;
}

public void setUserPostCategory(String userPostCategory) {
    this.mUserPostCategory = userPostCategory;
}

public void setUserPostEmail(String userPostEmail) {
    this.mUserPostEmail = userPostEmail;
}

public void setUserPostImages(List<UserPostAdsImages> userPostImages) {
    this.mUserPostImages = userPostImages;
}

public void setUserPostName(String userPostName) {
    this.mUserPostName = userPostName;
}

public void setUserPostPhonenumber(String userPostPhonenumber) {
    this.mUserPostPhonenumber = userPostPhonenumber;
}

public void setUserPostSupportingLanguage(List<UserPostAdsLanguages> userPostSupportingLanguage) {
    this.mUserPostSupportingLanguage = userPostSupportingLanguage;
}

public void setUserPostWebsite(String userPostWebsite) {
    this.mUserPostWebsite = userPostWebsite;
}

public String getUserPostAddress() {
    return mUserPostAddress;
}

public String getUserPostBusinessEndTime() {
    return mUserPostBusinessEndTime;
}

public String getUserPostBusinessSelectedCity() {
    return mUserPostBusinessSelectedCity;
}

public String getUserPostBusinessSelectedCountry() {
    return mUserPostBusinessSelectedCountry;
}

public String getUserPostBusinessStartTime() {
    return mUserPostBusinessStartTime;
}

public String getUserPostCategory() {
    return mUserPostCategory;
}

public String getUserPostEmail() {
    return mUserPostEmail;
}

public List<UserPostAdsImages> getUserPostImages() {
    return mUserPostImages;
}

public String getUserPostName() {
    return mUserPostName;
}

public String getUserPostPhonenumber() {
    return mUserPostPhonenumber;
}

public List<UserPostAdsLanguages> getUserPostSupportingLanguage() {
    return mUserPostSupportingLanguage;
}

public String getUserPostWebsite() {
    return mUserPostWebsite;
}
```

}

---

--> SubCategoryDisplayAdapter.class

```
  SubCategoryLoad subCategoryLoadCurrent = mSubCategoryLoad.get(position);
  holder.mSubCategoryAdsTitle.setText(subCategoryLoadCurrent.getUserPostName());
    holder.mSubCategoryAdsSupportingLanguagesList.setText("English,Japanese");

    //Log.i(TAG, "message:"+subCategoryLoadCurrent.getUserPostImages().get(0).getUserPostImageList());

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(subCategoryLoadCurrent.getUserPostImages().get(0).getUserPostImageList())
            .into(holder.mSubCategoryAdsImage);
```

---

Thanks & Regards,
Yeswanth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have the same issue with my parsing and the problem was instead of a list of custom objects i was supposed to be using a Map like this

```
private Map<String,Boolean>
```

That field in Firebase contains a key and a state  (True or False).

Also you can check the code on the docs to see how they parse these objects.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0#read_data_once

Comment: Hi Jose, Thanks for information & I have tried But unfortunately Same Error but this time it is occurring in Adapter. could you please help me.                                                     Error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to 
    SubCategoryLoad   (This call in Adapter)                                                                            Updated Model Class: SubCategoryLoad

Comment: Sure, ok, please share your new custom class and the method you are using to fill the adapter, also de adapter please.

Comment: Dear Jose, Thanks for your support.  My Problem resolved. It's really helped a lot.